Dokka: Include a markdown file when generating documentation
I'm trying to add a markdown file (README.md) when generating my documentation with Dokka, but the instruction doesn't seem to be taken into consideration... "includes" instruction.
Generate with cli :
java -jar ./dokka/dokka-cli-1.9.20.jar dokka-configuration.json

dokka-configuration.json
{
    "moduleName": "Scheduler",
    "moduleVersion": "0.0.1",
    "outputDir": "./doc",
    "failOnWarning": true,
    "offlineMode": false,
    "includes": [
        "README.md"
    ],
    "sourceSets": [
        {
            "displayName": "Name",
            "sourceSetID": {
                "scopeId": "compagny.com.scheduler",
                "sourceSetName": "main"
            },
            "sourceRoots": [
                "src/main"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "pluginsClasspath": [
        "./dokka/dokka-base-1.9.20.jar",
        "./dokka/kotlinx-html-jvm-0.11.0.jar",
        "./dokka/analysis-kotlin-descriptors-1.9.20.jar",
        "./dokka/freemarker-2.3.32.jar"
    ],
    "pluginsConfiguration": [
        {
        "fqPluginName": "org.jetbrains.dokka.base.DokkaBase",
        "serializationFormat": "JSON",
        "values": "{\"separateInheritedMembers\":false,\"footerMessage\":\"© 2024 XXX\"}"
        }
    ]
}

Thanks for the help !
